# How to pull data into separate tab based on two criteria from data added through Google Form responses

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am compiling quiz scores gathered from Google Forms on separate tabs to one tab called Scores. It needs to pull the data based on the email addresses gathered along with if the user scored 100%. The current formula I am using now is listed below, but I'm having difficulty adding the second piece of criteria to only pull instances where the score is 100%.

```
=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...","sheetName!A2:D100"),"select Col4 where Col2='email1@email1.com'")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "SheetName!A2:D100"), 
 "select Col4 
  where Col2='email1@email1.com' 
    and Col3="&100, 0)
```

or `100%` or `0.01` - depends on what formatting you use